# Logging all new processes in C

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I would like to create an event loop of sorts, that waits for new processes on a system.

I haven't the slightest clue where to begin, just looking for ideas

I apologize if my English is poor.

Comment: Er why? What you are asking for is not really supported. Those aren't real files and they only support some limited operations. If you explain your motivation, maybe we can suggest something else you could try instead.

Comment: I just need it to detect when a new process begins, thats the best way I could think of doing it

Comment: Check out [execsnoop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/execsnoop-bpfcc.8.html)